# ZF2 Controller actions execute common code

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Apologies if this is a basic question but I have attempted to find an answer in the ZF2 documentation and I can't find a clear answer.

I have a set of Controllers each containing a set of actions.  I would like each action to check for a certain parameter being present in the request.  What is the best to ensure that this gets done for all actions such that if I add a new action it will automatically be catered for too?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the [AbstractActionController](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Mvc.Controller.AbstractActionController.html) and add your custom methods or override existing ones to your needs.

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

abstract class AbstractCustomController extends AbstractActionController
{
   //custom methods
}
```

once That is done you then simply access your custom controller trough namespaces and extend it with the new controllers.

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Controller; 

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;    
use Custom\Controller\AbstractCustomController;

class NewController extends AbstractUserController {
   //new controller which has access to methods from extented AbstractController
}
```

You didnt specify on what exactly you are checking on. But using a [MVC Event](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#order-of-events) might be cleaner and easier to implement. You'll simply add some functionality to your `module.php` for example:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
//check request
}
```

This is just an example and may not work though. Depending on the Order of events the request may not be filled at this given point and you'd be forced to use another one.

I once used the `onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e)` provided by the `AbstractActionController` for a task that was a little bit similar to yours. But then again if you could be more specific we'd probably could give you a more specific answer.

best regards and good luck!

Edit: Regarding your question in the comment you could listen to the routing event and get your params there.

```
//Module.php within your onBootstrap Method
$application = $e->getApplication();
$eventManager = $application->getEventManager();
$eventManager->attach('route', function(MvcEvent $mvcEvent) {
   $params = $mvcEvent->getRouteMatch()->getParams();
   echo '<pre>'; print_r($params); exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  It's the onBootstrap event that I needed. Just one further question though, if you don't mind - how can I check a particular request parameter from within that function?  It's easy enough when my code was in an AbstractActionController, I just called: $this->params()->fromQuery('param_name'); How do I achieve the same thing from the onBootstrap function?  Using the $e event parameter somehow?

Comment: @eebsie I updated my answer is this what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks for your answer and that may well work. But I actually got this bit working with this line of code: `$e->getParams()["request"]->getQuery()->offsetGet('parameter-name');`